# How do I use objects to represent data from my relational database without making an excessive number of database queries?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, datamapper, select-n-plus-1

I'm trying to design my first complex object-oriented PHP application and I'm confused about how to use objects to represent data from my database. More specifically I'm confused about how to *combine multiple objects* without making a huge number of database queries.

A simple example: let's say I have two database tables:

```
products: - product_id
          - manufacturer_id
          - name
          - price

manufacturers: - manufacturer_id
               - name
               - factory_address
               - factory_zipcode
               - factory_country
               - // [50 additional columns]
```

I represent these using two classes:

```
class Product {}
class Manufacturer {}
```

Now let's say I want to create a page which lists 1000 products.

I create an array of 1000 `Product` objects using a `ProductFactory` class or similar, something like this:

```
class ProductFactory {
    function allProducts() {
        $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM products");
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $product_objects[] = new Product($result);
        }
        return $product_objects;
    }
}
```

That's fine. That's only a single database query and now I have all the product data - great!

But what if I want to create a slightly different page which also displays 1000 products, but also includes data from the manufacturers table?

Sure, I could change my query to use a `JOIN` to return columns from the manufacturer table as part of my product query, but that doesn't seem very flexible to me, because:

1. I might not always need manufacturer data, so loading it in the `ProductFactory` seems wasteful if I only use it on a single page and nowhere else.
2. The manufacturer data might be very extensive, and I don't want 50 extra columns bloating my query result when all I need is the manufacturer's name.
3. If I fetched product *and* manufacturer data in a single query I don't see how I could elegantly create two separate objects (`Product` and `Manufacturer`) from the query results without it being super messy.

I guess I could add a second method to my ProductFactory class, something like:

```
function allProductsWithManufacturerData() {
    // SELECT * FROM products JOIN manufacturers...
}
```

But that seems hacky and inflexible. People using my code would not know that they need to specifically call this method if they want to include manufacturer data in the Product objects.

Alternatively I could load data only when it's explicity requested:

```
echo $productObject->getManufacturer()->name;
```

That seems like a fairly flexible approach to me. But in my example above, that would result in 1000 extra queries (one for each product on the page) which would be horrible for performance.

**Also...** what if the Manufacturer object itself also loads a child object of its own? For example a Manufacturer might be associated with an Address object (`$Manufacturer->getAddress()->zipcode`). Fetching the Address object will require its own query too. So now our query chain is 3 queries deep:

- A query data for the Product object

  - For every Product... a query for the Product->Manufacturer object

    - For every Manufacturer... a query for the Manufacturer->Address object

This could quickly snowball into an exponentially increasing number of nested queries!

So it seems like I'm being forced into a choice:

1. Choose to fetch all the data you could ever possibly need at the "top level" (using a single query with JOIN statements)
2. Or... choose to fetch the bare minimum data and then use extra queries to fetch data as required.

Are these my only choices or am I missing something? Is there a design pattern I don't know about that I can use to leverage more flexibility here?

Comment: Use an existing ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @Barmar I am interested in knowing *how* such a problem would be solved, i.e. the architecture involved and how the data/objects interact with each other. Yours might be a valid suggestion but I'd like to have the knowledge before I use an existing tool.

Comment: I believe the way most ORMs work is that they execute the query lazily. When you add conditions to the query, it just updates an internal data structure that represents the query logic. The query doesn't execute until you actually ask to fetch something, then it constructs the query from all the options you used.

Comment: @Barmar "just use ORM" teaches you nothing.

Comment: @tereško When I made that comment I didn't understand that this was an academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve this issue :)

Let's assume you already got your 1000 products, with manufacturers that only have ID (which you got by selecting from only `products` table).

```php
$manufacturers = []; 
// I would actually use a Collection class, but that's not important here

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $manufacturers[] = $product->getManufacturer();
}

$manufacturerMapper->populate($manufacturers);
```

Then the [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) for manufacturers makes a single select with `WHERE manufacturer_id IN (....)` condition and "fills in" all of the objects using the setters.

What this relies on is the following behavior:

```php
$foo = new Thing;
$bar = $foo;
$bar->setStuff('blah');
var_dump($foo->getStuff() === 'blah'); /// TRUE
```

The list manufacturers that you passes to the mapper are *the same* manufacturers that already exist inside the product entities.

### The flaw

This is not a perfect solution, because you have to handle "the manufacturers repeat" situation. While you are dealing with 1:1 case, it's not all that tricky (you just need to make an "index" inside the mapper to know all entries with matching PK).

But this does not actually scale all that well.

The "more correct" way is to use something called [Identity map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) that acts as something like a runtime-cache either inside your mappers or your repositories. The first time I encountered the concept was when I as reading about how to make "proper [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)".

Core of the solution is creation of this behavior:

```php
$first = $repo->get(45);
$second = $repo->get(45);

$first->setTitle('Lorem Ipsum');
var_dump($second->getTitle() === 'Lorem Ipsum'); // TRUE
```

This looks a lot like the previous bit, but the important past is that the repository is NOT returning an entity with *same data*, but instead is returning the **same entity**.

I personally implemented this behavior at the mapper-level and not in the repositories themselves, but YMMV.

If you are just starting with OOP, ignore this "overkill" solution and stick with the first part :) This extended version requires some boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I thought about this approach (first get all the manufacturer_ids and then make a single `IN (...)` query using those ids. That works well with a total of just 2 queries. **However** let's say my Manufacturer object also has some child objects which need to be fetched in the same way. Now I have 3 queries. Maybe those child objects have children as well... that's 4 queries... you see where I'm going with this? Is there not some design pattern which can "layer up" all of these objects into one single large query with JOINs instead? Maybe not but I'd like to know.

Comment: In a real world the amount of "layers" will be finite (and, honestly, very small). You are solving a problem, that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here. One is practical and easily answerable. And another one  simply has no answer.

The first one is "How do I use objects to represent data from my relational database without making an excessive number of database queries?" and JOIN is the most *natural* answer to your predicament, and I don't see much point in the objections you made.

#1 and #2 and are actually the same, and honestly, I don't see how it makes any problem. If you don't need the manufacturer data, then don't use a JOIN query. As simple as that.

#3 can be easily resolved with `PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES`

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM product p JOIN manufacturer m ON m.id=p.id");
$row = pdo_table_separator($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
$product =  new Product($row['product']);
$product->manufacturer = new Manufacturer($row['manufacturer']);

function pdo_table_separator($row) {
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        [$table, $column] = explode(".", $col);
        $return[$table][$column] = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Your second question is "how to make my objects to represent my relational data" and it has *no* (satisfying) answer. Some even [compare this problem with Vietnam War](https://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) that gets harder with each foothold you gain and that you inevitably lose anyway.

So you can just comfort yourself that it's not a problem with your experience or a certain pattern that you just don't know yet.

You can add some strategies, such as "lazy load" (your fetch when needed) or "eager load" (tereško's get manufacturers' ids, fetch them in one go and graft the results into products). You can add some switch that tells your code which strategy to use. But you see, there is essentially *no* solution that doesn't seem hacky or  inflexible.

Personally, I would let my PHP code to write SQL for me only for the most basic queries. While every other query, including one requesting products with manufacturers, I'd write explicitly, accompanied with a mapping code, altogether put in a method of a repository class.